# MFMailComposeViewController will not dismiss

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, dismiss

After following a tutorial that showed me how to implement In-App Mail, it seems to fail upon the cancel button and send button to dismiss the view.

Now I have read a few comments on here that say I should implement this method:

```
-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But that does not solve the issue, not in the simulator or on my iPhone 4 - The message does get send though, but the view does not dismiss.

This is my code so far:

```
#pragma mark - InApp Mail
- (IBAction)openMail:(id)sender
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];


    [mailer setSubject:@"iOS School - MultipleAlertViews"];

    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email
    NSString *pathFile01 = @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61711378/iOS%20School%20-%20Docs/MultipleAlertViewsVCh.pdf";
    NSURL *pdfURLFile01 = [NSURL URLWithString:pathFile01];
    NSData *pdfDataFile01 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfURLFile01];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:pdfDataFile01 mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MultipleAlertViewsVCh.pdf"];

    NSString *pathFile02 = @"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61711378/iOS%20School%20-%20Docs/MultipleAlertViewsVCm.pdf";
    NSURL *pdfURLFile02 = [NSURL URLWithString:pathFile02];
    NSData *pdfDataFile02 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfURLFile02];
    [mailer addAttachmentData:pdfDataFile02 mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"MultipleAlertViewsVCm.pdf"];


    NSString *emailBody = 
    @"Hello,<br/><br/>You requested code for this project, which you can now use in XCode <br/><br/> You will find 2 Attachements.<br/>One is the Header file and the other is the Implementation file.<br/><br/>Thank you for using this app, if you find it useful, don't forget to give it a Rating in the App Store.<br/><br/>Kind Regards,<br/>iOS School";


    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                    message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
        break;
}

// Remove the mail view
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

As you can see, I have implemented that 
`- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller    didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error`

But it is not working - anything else I am missing - I am using iOS 5.1

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've implemented the delegate method, but haven't set the delegate:

```
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

After you create `mailer`.

Comment: Thank you that was it - I have to wait 10 minutes before I can accept your answer, but will do it later:-)